# ajax.edn not available when importing in cljs

Tags: clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I'm importing ajax.edn in my cljs project like so:

```
(:require [ajax.edn :as edn])
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ajax.edn isn't available.
```

I do have cljs-ajax/cljs-ajax in my deps.edn like so:

```
cljs-ajax/cljs-ajax {:mvn/version "0.8.1"}
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Please provide a full minimal failing example. There are steps to be done to use clj-cli and shadow-cljs; see https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#deps-edn

Comment: Import it like that
`cljs-ajax {:mvn/version "0.8.1"}`